# How to get rid of warning C4518: storage-class or type specifier(s) unexpected here; ignored

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm inheriting an old DLL project in C++. It compiles using VS 6.0.

It is a thing that had been working for years.

First thing I notice when I build the project is some warnings that usually are related to missing semicolons, but this is not the case, please take a look:

Warning in the header file:

```
someproject\include\somefile.h(27) : warning C4518: '__declspec(dllexport) ' : storage-class or type specifier(s) unexpected here; ignored
```

Code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    VOID    DLLExport WINAPI func1        (unsigned char  *c, SHORT b, BOOL bIsChar, SomeTask* spTask);

    VOID    DLLExport WINAPI func2        (unsigned char  *c, SHORT b, BOOL bIsChar, SomeTask* spTask);
    PBYTE   DLLExport WINAPI func3          (PBYTE cpStr, BYTE cCh);
    SomeTask*   DLLExport WINAPI TaskPtr(VOID); // <- Ofending line
```

Warning in the cpp file:

```
someproject\somecode.cpp(3264) : warning C4518: '__declspec(dllexport ) ' : storage-class or type specifier(s) unexpected here; ignored
```

Code:

```
extern "C" SomeTask* DLLExport WINAPI TaskPtr(VOID)
{
    blah(); 
    blah();
```

Code for the class:

```
class SomeTask
{
public:
    SomeTask(){}
            etc
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you still using VS 6 to compile?

Comment: It has a lot of macros.  Without know what they expand to, it will be difficult to help.

Comment: @masrtis It's an old inherited DLL. My task is to port it to a newer compiler version, but frankly I'm just in C++ 101 level. So I'll learn and work at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The message seems to imply that `dllexport(winapi)` is a language extension which behaves like a storage class or type specifier. Such terms can appear in any order but typically storage class comes before type: we say `static int` not `int static`. This code uses the unusual ordering and that is apparently unsupported by the older compiler. But in this case it won't matter unless you build a DLL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The part that I don't understand is why the syntax error comes from that line only. If you see the code, previous declarations have the same exact syntax, in that order. But it is that pointer to a class the one C++ generate a warning for.

Comment: @CraigStevensson Well, you never told us which line the error refers to.

Comment: It was the "SomeTask*   DLLExport WINAPI TaskPtr(VOID); "

Comment: As already mentioned, we also need to know what the macros are expanding to.